# How transform chain's promises into flat promise in Q and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, q

I want to know if there is a way to transform chain's promises in a flat promise. I have this code:

```
import * as Q from 'q';
export class MyClass {

  private methodA(): Q.Promise<boolean> {
    let deferred = Q.defer<boolean>();
    //some stuff, like database calls, etc
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  private methodB(): Q.Promise<boolean> {
    let deferred = Q.defer<boolean>();
    //some stuff, like database calls, etc
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  private methodC(): Q.Promise<boolean> {
    let deferred = Q.defer<boolean>();
    //some stuff, like database calls, etc
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  private methodD(): Q.Promise<boolean> {
    let deferred = Q.defer<boolean>();
    //some stuff, like database calls, etc
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  run(): Q.Promise<boolean> {
    let deferred = Q.defer<boolean>();
    let promises = [];

    promises.push(this.methodA().then(wasOk => {
      this.methodB().then(wasOk => {
        this.methodC();
      });
    }));

    promises.push(this.methodD());

    //Wait all promises
    Q.all(promises).then(wasOk => deferred.resolve(wasOk));

    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

This code have one problem: Q.all only is waiting to methodA and methodD; and is not waiting for methodB and methodC.

I think I will need to put method B and C in promises's vector, or even make another vector and wait for it inside first Q.all... but it will be not a clear code, and I wondering if there a better aproach.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing a `return` in your `then` handler on `methodA`, and probably within its `then` handler, because you're using *verbose* arrow functions:

```
promises.push(this.methodA().then(wasOk => {
  return this.methodB().then(wasOk => {
//^^^^^^^
    return this.methodC();
//  ^^^^^^^
  });
}));
```

Or with *concise* arrow functions:

```
promises.push(this.methodA().then(wasOk => this.methodB().then(wasOk => this.methodC())));
```

Or with concise arrows with line breaks:

```
promises.push(this.methodA().then(wasOk =>
  this.methodB().then(wasOk =>
    this.methodC()
  )
));
```

Note that that code does this:

- Calls `methodA` and waits for it to resolve, then
- Calls `methodB` and waits for it to resolve, then
- Calls `methodC`

So overall, the first promise in your array won't resolve until `methodB` and `methodC` resolve; `methodD` is called right away and so could resolve sooner.

The array construction could be simpler as well:

```
promises = [
  this.methodA().then(wasOk =>
    this.methodB().then(wasOk =>
      this.methodC()
    )
  ),
  this.methodD()
];
```

Comment: You are right. In my original code, method B and C never was invoked. My problem is that in this chain, method B and C only need to be invoked depending on result on parent promise, so I need braces to put some "if" inside them. I will update my question with more real code. Thanks!

Comment: @VladimirVenegas: The above allows `methodB` to use the result of `methodA`, and allows `methodC` to use the results of both `methodA` and `methodB`. The only one that isn't in the chain (it's in parallel) is `methodD`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a slight error, almost a typo:

```
promises.push(this.methodA().then(wasOk => {
      this.methodB().then(wasOk => {
        this.methodC();
      });
    }));
```

It's the curly braces -- they change a return of a promise into a return of undefined.  You could do this:

```
promises.push(this.methodA().then(wasOk => 
      this.methodB().then(wasOk => 
        this.methodC();
      );
    ));
```

or this:

```
promises.push(this.methodA().then(wasOk => {
      return this.methodB().then(wasOk => {
        return this.methodC();
      });
    }));
```

or even this:

```
promises = [this.methodA(), this.methodB(), this.methodC()];
```